# Extract entity from last seven days core data

Tags: swift, core-data, nsdate, nspredicate

I am currently working with core data to store meals. My entities are date (Date), foods (string) and drinks (string). Now I want to extract all the foods stored for the last seven days. How would I do this? I know i should somehow use NSPredicate, but I can't figure out how exactly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get the current calendar

```
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
```

Get the current date

```
let now = NSDate()
```

Subtract 7 days from current date

```
let sevenDaysAgo = calendar.dateByAddingUnit(.Day, value: -7, toDate: now, options: [])!
```

Get the start of the day 7 days ago

```
let startDate = calendar.startOfDayForDate(sevenDaysAgo)
```

Create the predicate, literal `date` is the Core Data attribute

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format:"(date >= %@) AND (date < %@)", startDate, now)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! But how could I extract one day at the time (but still all of the seven days)? The reason I want to do this is because I want to take the mean value for days when there is more than one stored value for each day. Or maybe there is a better way to do this?

Comment: Executing a fetch request using this predicate returns an array of all objects matching the condition. Add a sort descriptor to get a sorted array. Then enumerate the array. Or use one fetch request for each day.

Comment: That's for the past 2 days, for single days subtract one and keep the value in a variable. Then in a loop take the variable as `end date`, subtract one again, save it in the variable and take the new value as `start date`.